# When can I expect to get 5 heads in a row when tossing a coin?

Tags: probability, expected-value

A coin that lands on heads with probability $p$ is flipped until either $n$ consecutive heads appear or $n$ consecutive tails appear. What is the expected number of coin tosses?
I get 
$$\mathbb{E}[C_n]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[C_n|H]]=\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=1]\mathbb{P}(H=1)+\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=0](1-\mathbb{P}(H=1))$$
Where 

$C_n$ is the number of flips until we get either $n$ consecutive heads or $n$ consecutive tails. $H=1$ iff we get $n$ consecutive heads before $n$ consecutive tails and is zero otherwise.
$$\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=1]=\frac {p^{-n}-1}{1-p}$$
$$\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=0]=\frac {(1-p)^{-n}-1}{p}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(H=1)=\frac{p^{n}}{1-(1-p^{n-1})(1-(1-p)^{n-1})}+(1-p)p^{n-1}\frac{1-(1-p)^{n-1}}{1-(1-p^{n-1})(1-(1-p)^{n-1})}$$
As an answer, but, when trying to compute this value when $p=1$, which better be $n$, it is $2n$. what is wrong with the formula?

PS:

The way I got the terms is as follows:

If the first flip is tails, then the conditional expected value is $1+\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=1]$, if the first flip is heads and the second tails, the conditional expected value is $2+\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=1]$, if ..., thus 
$$\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=1]=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p^k(1-p)(1+k+\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=1])$$
Solving for $\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=1]$ gives
$$\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=1]=\frac{p^{-n}-1}{1-p}$$
Likewise for $\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=0]$ except that the probabilities are now inverted, thus:
$$\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=0]=\frac{(1-p)^{-n}-1}{p}$$
To compute $\mathbb{P}(H=1)$ we condition on whether the first flip is a head. Here, we have two possibilities, either the following $n-1$ flips are heads, or one of these $n-1$ flips results in tails, at which point we forget about all previous heads and imagine that our first flip is a tail, thus
$$P=\mathbb{P}(H=1|\text{first flip is heads})=p^{n-1}+(1-p^{n-1})\mathbb{P}(H=1|\text{first flip is tails})$$
To compute $\mathbb{P}(H=1|\text{first flip is tails})$, we have two possibilities again: either the following $n-1$ flips are all tails, in which case the probability of obtaining $n$ consecutive heads before $n$ consecutive tails is zero, or somewhere along the line we get a head, in which case we start all over again as if though our first flip had been a head. Thus
$$Q=\mathbb{P}(H=1|\text{first flip is tails})=(1-(1-p)^{n-1})\mathbb{P}(H=1|\text{first flip is heads})$$
We now have the simultaneous equations
$$\begin{align} P&=p^{n-1}+(1-p^{n-1})Q \\ Q &=(1-(1-p)^{n-1})P\end{align}$$
Which implies that $$P=\frac{p^{n-1}}{1-(1-p^{n-1})(1-(1-p)^{n-1})}$$
$$Q=\frac{p^{n-1}(1-(1-p)^{n-1})}{1-(1-p^{n-1})(1-(1-p)^{n-1})}$$
Remembering we had conditioned on the first flip, we now get
$$\mathbb{P}(H=1)=\frac{p^{n}}{1-(1-p^{n-1})(1-(1-p)^{n-1})}+(1-p)p^{n-1}\frac{1-(1-p)^{n-1}}{1-(1-p^{n-1})(1-(1-p)^{n-1})}$$

Comment: The notation is very confusing.

Comment: @MichaelChernick what can I do to improve it?

Comment: What is C_n?  What do you mean by P(H=1)?  Seems like you are considering an event when you get 5 heads in a row and not just one head ? The two recursions don't make sense. Why do you get "if the first flip is a tail the conditional expectation is 1+E(C_n|H=1) and if the first flip is a head the conditional expectation is 2+E(C_n|H=1).  Since I don't understand what this notation means and I don't follow these two results given the result of the first flip, I can't follow the next step. Your question is getting a lot of upvotes but no answers.

Comment: I think people are impressed by the chain of equations even though they probably don't really understand what you are doing.  It does seem that there should be a way to write a recursion by conditioning on the first flip but I can't get past the problems I am having with the notation.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I explained both $C_n$ and $H$, please tell me if there are other things that are left unclear.

Comment: What exactly does "H=0" mean? If it means exactly one tail has been observed, then your starting equations are incorrect: the conditional expectations for $C_n$ appear to assume that this problem is equivalent to two separate problems (one involving strings of heads only and another involving strings of tails only), but it's not.

Comment: $H=0$ means that $n$ consecutive heads are not seen before $n$ consecutive tails, therefore it means that $n$ consecutive tails happen first. And I know the solution is incorrect, what I want to know is why it is so close to the actual solution (i.e. only scaled by a factor of 2)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't follow your derivation, but I believe the correct way to solve the problem is as follows.

First, some notation: take $x_i$ to be the expected number of flips to reach the end state ($n$ consecutive heads or $n$ consecutive tails), given that we're on a "run" of exactly $i$ consecutive flips of heads. Similarly, take $y_i$ to be the expected number of flips to reach the end state, given that we're on a run of exactly $i$ consecutive flips of tails. Clearly, $x_n = y_n = 0$, since if we've already had $n$ consecutive heads or tails, we're done.

Then, we're interested in finding $x_0$ ($= y_0$). The relevant equations are (for $i < n$):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x_i & = (1-p)(1 + y_1) + p(1 + x_{i+1}) \\
y_i & = p(1 + x_1) + (1-p)(1 + y_{i+1})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Let's derive the first equation (the second one is analogous). Suppose we're on a run of $i$ heads. We want to find the expected number of flips to end the game, which is $x_i$. Let's take our next flip. There's a probability $p$ that it comes up heads, which means we now have a run of $i+1$ heads. That's the second term on the right-hand-side of the equation: there's a probability of $p$ of moving from the state with $i$ consecutive heads to the state with $i+1$ consecutive heads, and it costs 1 flip in order to do so. There's also a probability $1-p$ that it comes up tails, in which case we have a run of only 1 tail. That's the first term on the right-hand-side of the equation: there's a probability of $1-p$ of moving from the state with $i$ consecutive heads to the state with 1 consecutive tail, and it costs us 1 flip in order to do so.

With these equations you can solve the problem for any $n$. I tried implementing this in Mathematica, and if $p = 0$ or $p = 1$, I indeed get that $x_0 = y_0 = n$, as expected. <s>I'm not sure if there's any closed form solution to the equations for arbitrary $n$; that's probably a question for the Math StackExchange.</s> (Edit: see derivation below for the solution for arbitrary $n$).

What I've sketched out here is a general approach for solving many types of coin flipping problems (and other problems). It essentially constructs a Markov chain that has states (e.g., 3 consecutive heads), and transition probabilities for moving between states (e.g., a probability of $1-p$ of moving from 3 consecutive heads to 1 tail). The absorbing states are the end states of the game. See, for instance, [the answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116464/coin-flips-and-markov-chain).

EDIT: For the particular case of $n=5$, I get (using Mathematica):

\begin{equation}
x_0 = \frac{(5 - 10p + 10p^2 - 5p^3 + p^4)(1 + p + p^2 + p^3 + p^4)}{1 - 4p + 6p^2 - 4p^3 + p^4 + 4p^5 - 6p^6 + 4p^7 - p^8}
\end{equation}

which seems to have the right limits (although it's possible I have a typo somewhere).

Edit #2: Following @whuber's advice, I solved the recurrence relation for general $n$. The solution is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\ y_0
\end{bmatrix}
=
(A + B)[(I-A^{n-1})^{-1}(I-A)-B]^{-1}c + c
\end{equation}

where
\begin{equation}
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
p & 0 \\
0 & 1-p
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1-p \\
p & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
c = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

and $I$ is the identity matrix.
For $n=5$, this gives the same result as above.

Comment: If you write out the recursion in matrix form, it will be easy to derive a formula in closed form.

Comment: @whuber I was able to derive a closed form solution for this particular problem (with n = 5), but how would I do it for the case of arbitrary n? It seems like the size of the matrix would change, since for larger n there are more states.

Comment: Since the recurrence relations govern $x_i$ and $y_i$, consider the vector $v_i=(x_i,y_i)^\prime$ and write the recurrence relations in the form $$v_{i+1}=\mathbb{A}v_i + \mathbb{B}v_1 + c$$ for *fixed* matrices $\mathbb{A},\mathbb{B}$ and *fixed* constant vector $c=(1,1)^\prime$.  This recurrence is no more difficult to solve than its counterpart in one dimension, where $\mathbb{A},\mathbb{B},$ and $c$ are all just numbers. It helps to know how to sum geometric series; for instance, $1+p+\cdots+p^4=(1-p^5)/(1-p)$ allows the formula to be given in a closed form.

Comment: Where did you encounter difficulties understanding my derivation. I appreciate the effort you put into the answer, but my question was with regards to why is my solution scaled by $2$?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not quite sure your solution is wrong. I looked through your derivation again, and I think I understand it ok now. I'm suspicious of the first line, actually. For instance, suppose the coin is fair. Then, the equation reduces to $E[C_n] = E[C_n|H = 1]$, which is not true, at least with how you've defined $E[C_n|H=1]$. I think there's some sort of abuse of conditional expectation notation, although I can't quite figure it out. My feeling is that what you've calculated as $E[C_n|H=1]$ is actually the joint expectation, not the conditional.

Comment: I'd suggest solving this problem first: suppose $n=1$, so we just want 1 consecutive head or tail. Also suppose the coin is fair, to make the algebra easier. It's obvious that $E[C_1] = 1$ (regardless of whether the coin is fair or not). Your formula doesn't seem to return the right result in this situation, because the conditional expectations ($E[C_n|H=1]$, etc.) are all larger than 1.